# Parsing a sentence with a て connecting verb

Tags: て-form

This sentence is from NHK newsweb easy.

> 政府は、新型インフルエンザ（＝人から人にうつる今までになかった新しいインフルエンザ）が世界で流行して、日本でも大勢の人が亡くなる心配がある場合、どうするかというガイドライン（方針）の案を作りました。

I'll remove the easier parts and try to reduce it to the part i'm having trouble parsing...

> 政府は、インフルエンザが流行して、人が亡くなる心配がある場合、どうするかというガイドラインの案を作りました。

I can't figure out how 流行して plays into the sentence. I have two main ideas...

(1) インフルエンザが流行して is a high-level clause, and the rest of the sentence after して should be treated as a unit. The flu is spreading in reality.

(2) インフルエンザが流行して、人が亡くなる心配がある場合 goes together; the spreading of the flu causes people to die/causes people to worry about people dying. The flu is not necessarily spreading in reality, it is just a hypothetical situation (場合).

Comment: What if the flu *is* spreading around the world... and the Japanese government *has* proactively set up guidelines on how to deal with the flu and how to calm any potential public *(national)* fear related to the incoming flu? ^^;

Comment: That sounds like (1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A -て form is usually linked to its sentence. You cannot guess what is happening without the end.

-郵便局行って
 - 帰る。 *I'll pass by the post office and go home.*
 - 帰った。 *I passed by the post office then went gome.*

It is your second guess the correct one.

> インフルエンザが流行して、人が亡くなる心配がある

*They think/fear people are gonna die because the flu is spreading.*

Then, you add a context condition on it with `場合`. Which means nothing is happening.

*The government made a guideline plan about what to do **in the case** they think people are gonna die as a result of the flu spreading.*

**Edit** Different point of views

> (oldergod) 政府は、インフルエンザが流行して、人が亡くなる心配がある場合、どうするかというガイドラインの案を作りました。
>   (oldergod) ①インフルエンザが流行ってるから、人が亡くなる心配がでる可能性を考えて案を作ったか
>   (oldergod) ②インフルエンザが流行する場合は人が亡くなる心配がでるまでの時の案を作ったか
>   (oldergod) どちらのでしょう
>   (mukai) なんか、わかりにくい文ですが、①ではないです。
>   (mukai) 今は流行していない。流行した場合も人が死ぬかどうかはわからない。でも、もし、流行して、かつ、人が死ぬかもしれない場合、どうするか、というガイドラインを作る、ということですね。
>   (akagi) 難解ですな (akagi) 人に話す場合は多分②じゃ意味不明と言われてしまいそうです
>   (akagi) が、例文と同じ意味になるのは②ってことなのかな

As you can see, everyone is getting a hard time.

I just personally think that it is definitly your second guess. They don't make a plan for one season flu. They'll use it everytime there is the flu spreading around.

Comment: "A -て form is usually linked to its sentence" Not sure if I'm understanding this correctly, but isn't the very question whether "its sentence" is "人が亡くなる" or "...作りました"? I don't think anyone is suggesting that the -て is just dangling.

Comment: @dainichi the OP's first guess says so, am I wrong?

Comment: Hm... I can't say for sure, but I assumed they meant インフルエンザが流行して、政府は案を作った

Comment: @dainichi yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @ogicu8abruok　(2)ですよね。「もし」を入れてみたらどうでしょう？「政府は、『もし』インフルが世界中で流行して日本でも死者が大勢出る可能性が出てきたらどうするか・・・」って感じで。